# Retrieve IMAP Subfolders

Tags: c#, mailkit

I am trying to retrieve the subfolders and messages from the inbox but i was only able to retrieve the parent subfolders, also tried with PersonalNamespaces[0]

```
var inbox = client.Inbox;
inbox.Open (FolderAccess.ReadWrite);

Debug.WriteLine ("Total messages: {0}", inbox.Count);
//client.Inbox.Status(StatusItems.Unread);
//Debug.WriteLine("Recent messages: {0}", inbox.Unread);
//Debug.WriteLine("Recent messages: {0}", inbox.FirstUnread);

var personal = client.GetFolder(client.PersonalNamespaces[0]);

foreach (var folder in inbox.GetSubfolders(false))
{
        Console.WriteLine("[folder] {0}", folder.Name);
        folder.Open(FolderAccess.ReadOnly);
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 4):

Not all IMAP servers will even allow subfolders of the INBOX folder. If you are sure that your IMAP account's INBOX folder has subfolders, you would use the following code snippet to get them:

```
foreach (var folder in client.Inbox.GetSubfolders (false)) {
    Console.WriteLine ("[folder] {0}", folder.Name);
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, I tried that before but doesnt work either, my IMAP account has subfolders and they can be seen in outlook and webmail, i also made them subscribed but result is the same, is there any other way? Thanks

Comment: If MailKit isn't finding any subfolders of INBOX, then there aren't any. To confirm this, you can take a look at the protocol log by following these instructions: https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/FAQ.md#ProtocolLog

Comment: Here you can see the subfolders in outlook: http://prntscr.com/79ldh4 is there anything incorrect?

Comment: What does the protocol log say?

Comment: I think I found a bug that might cause this. The problem is likely due to the fact that the INBOX folder name is case-insensitive and ImapFolder.GetSubfolders() filters out folders returned by the server that do not start with the ImapFolder's name in order to work around a server bug: https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/issues/149

Comment: Yes its smartermail so what is the way around the problem? thank you

Comment: I've committed a patch to fix the problem, but I probably won't have a chance to make a new release until this weekend. You can use GitHub and build from source in the meantime, however.

Comment: thanks a lot for your work i will wait for the release

Comment: in mimekit.internetaddress i can only get name, how about the email address ? thank you

Comment: What you'll need to do is cast the InternetAddress to a MailboxAddress and then use the Address property. InternetAddress is the abstract base class for MailboxAddress and GroupAddress.

Comment: Thanks again for the help :) let me know when you make the release in nuget if possible, at the moment i have one problem i am trying to move a message from inbox to deleted items folder but keep getting error folder not open (but i user folder.Open(ReadWrite) in both folders), only deleted items stays open which is the one that i opened last

Comment: The way IMAP works is that only the last folder to be opened remains open. Previously opened folders are automatically closed. The destination folder for the APIs that copy and move messages does not need to be open, only the source folder needs to be open.

Comment: I tried that way too but keep getting the same error:
Additional information: Unexpected token in IMAP response: [atom: 0]
Here is my code:                                 if (inbox.IsOpen == true)
                                {
                                    inbox.MoveTo(uid, folder);
                                }  After checking the webmail the message appears in inbox and also recreates a new one in deleted items

Comment: Can you paste a protocol log into a new bug report in the https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit issue tracker? See https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/FAQ.md#ProtocolLog for help getting a protocol log. As far as the message showing up in 2 places, see this: https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/issues/160

Comment: I've made a new release of MailKit to NuGet.